# How do I transpose a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, transpose

| Parameter | Value | Data_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| window | 1024 | Data1 |
| noverlap | 256 | Data1 |
| ylim_min | 0 | Data1 |
| ylim_max | 500 | Data1 |
| mag_min | 0 | Data1 |
| max_max | 30 | Data1 |
| window | 2500 | Data2 |
| noverlap | 64 | Data2 |
| ylim_min | 0 | Data2 |
| ylim_max | 50 | Data2 |
| mag_min | 0 | Data2 |
| mag_max | 2500 | Data2 |

How do I transpose this pyspark data frame such as:

[image]

Comment: Using which language?

Comment: Using python but in pyspark dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is almost same as pandas dataframe

Let the dataframe is `df`

```
pivotdf= df.groupBy("Data_Type").pivot("Parameter").sum("Value")
pivotdf.show()
```

Here we are pivoting the column `Parameter` by grouping the column `Data_Type`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. After that I was actually trying to filter the pyspark dataframe by taking like rows from 40 to 50. The limit function will only take like first n rows. Is there a way to chunk the dataframe with a range?  Example: like this df=df.limit[40:50]

Comment: @emma19 As you need specific range `df.collect()[2:5]` but it will not give the output as dataframe format
 
If you are looking for a dataframe format then try like this `df.toPandas()[2:5]` but if I am not wrong this will lose the  distributed properties of spark but gives nice formatting